# Prove that if matrix AA is invertible then A is invertible

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing, inverse, matrix-rank

Suppose $AA$ is an invertible matrix, how would you prove that $A$ is invertible?

My Attempt:
consider the equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ then $AA\vec{x}=A\vec{0}=\vec{0}$ since $AA$ is invertible then by the invertible matrix theorem since Nul(AA) ={$\vec{0}$} the unique solution for $\vec{x}$ is $\vec{0}$ so by the system Rank theorem and the fact that A is a squrae matrix rank(A)=n and thus A is invertible. Would this be a correct proof, or am I assuming to much by stating that $\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ is the only solution to $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$?

Comment: Your idea is fine (1 step that might be missing is the implication that Nul(AA) is trivial implies that nul(A) is trivial). But the best and easiest way to do it is to find $B$ such that $BAA=I$ so $BA$ is the inverse of $A$.

Comment: why would this be the preferred method?

Comment: Just because it is a 1 line proof. And it is a direct proof by definition.

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction suppose $Ax=0$ for some $x\neq 0$ then $AAx=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B=(AA)^{-1}$. Then $A(AB)=(AA)B=I$ and $(BA)A=B(AA)=I$. Thus $A$ has right and left inverse and hence $AB=BA$ is the inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\det{AA}\neq0$$ and $$\det{AA}=\left(\det{A}\right)^2\neq0,$$
which gives $\det{A}\neq0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $B=A(AA)^{-1}$. What is $AB$?